# Methods for inAppPurchase implementation.

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I want to sell E-books and photos online through in app purchase of appStore. For that I would like to know the following things before proceeding to the in app purchase implementation.

Is it possible to copy the downloaded e-book to another computer?

Normally if we download images or pdf books via inAppPurchase means where these contents will be saved into the device (iPhone,/iPad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple In-App purchase is well suited for your requirement.

**Answer 1:**

I could not not transfer downloaded to others computer.

**Answer 2:**

What ever file you download in the application are stored in your application sandbox, So once the application is installed/Removed  user will lost all downloaded/stored data.

Comment: In case the device is jailbroken, the user can copy every file within the sandbox to any other computer.